# Call dispatchEvent from within exported named function

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I setup a Javascript utility LWC called sharedJs.  In the sharedJs.js file, I defined the following function:

```
const showToast = (title, message, severity) => {
    const evt = new CustomEvent('toastevent', {
        bubbles: true, 
        composed: true, 
        detail: {
            title: title,
            message: message,
            severity: severity,
            autoHideInterval: 5000
            }
        }
    );
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

export { showToast }
```

When I call showToast() from within a component that imports that method, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined
```

How do I call dispatchEvent() correctly?  Or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` won't be set from an external file, so you'd have to pass in the component to use:

```
  onclick() {
    showToast(this, 'title','message','severity')
  }
```

...

```
export function showToast(component, title, message, severity) {
    const evt = new CustomEvent('toastevent', {
        bubbles: true, 
        composed: true, 
        detail: {
            title: title,
            message: message,
            severity: severity,
            autoHideInterval: 5000
            }
        }
    );
    component.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/OTpJMBQIl7L4UG41px8p/src/showevent.js)

Note that even the built-in [ShowToastEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) requires you to dispatch it yourself:

```
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    showToast() {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Get Help',
            message: 'Salesforce documentation is available in the app. Click ? in the upper-right corner.',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Coincidentally, I looked up the source code, and here's what it looks like:

```
class ShowToastEvent extends CustomEvent {
  constructor(toast) {
    super(ShowToastEventName, {
      composed: true,
      cancelable: true,
      bubbles: true
    });
    platformNotificationUtils.showToast(toast, forceShowToastAttributes => {
      Object.defineProperties(this, {
        toastAttributes: {
          value: forceShowToastAttributes,
          writable: false
        }
      });
    });
  }

}
```

See? It's just a CustomEvent that does stuff, and is then fired by your own component code.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!